# How to create augmented reality style animation in real life videos?

Tags: animation, video

I was wondering how the 2D animations in a real life video is made? Like this one
http://www.adobe.com/in/solutions/digital-analytics.html - (watch the first video). There are many animations which are done in relative to real life objects.

[image: screenshot of animation]

How these are done? What software are suitable for these?

I didn't found any tutorials on this type of animation (or maybe I don't the perfect name of this type of animation). Can you give me some links?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of ways to do these, you'll probably want to look into Adobe After Effects. My favorite tutorial site for AE is [VideoCopilot](http://www.videocopilot.net/)

Then you need to overlay the AE Project on top of your video. For some things you may need to do 3D Modeling and Animation in a suite like Maya or 3DMax as well. It kinda depends on what exactly you're going for.

Found this which you might find interesting as well, shows a little behind the scenes and you can see just how much production and people are involved in something like this: http://www.blind.com/work/project/windowsphone7/

A better StackExchange for Video is aptly called [video.stackexchange.com](https://video.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't know better, but perhaps more suitable :P

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable software for this type of effects is Adobe After Effects.

I'm working on the Fantastic Imago Branding, Advertising & Consulting Agency, and we have done a big video project and we used the same technique that you want.

It's call tracking. We have tracked and retouched the nails of main actress.

[Here](http://world.fantasticimago.com/case-study-perla-de-plata-de-mallorca-fairy-tale), you can learn more about this project, this is a case study, maybe it will be useful for you.

Also you can find a lot of videos on YouTube how to do this type effect:

www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tracking+the+video+in+After+Effects

Firstly, you need to create the design of diagrams and charts in Adobe Photoshop, than export them in After Effects and than make tracking of the video and than animate graphics with tracking video. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different elements here.

1. The animation itself.
2. The tracking of the video footage.

So it is a two step process. Making the animation, making the video tracking.

Both steps can be done in a **compositing program**.

Yes. **I love free software**, so my recommendations for this are:

- **HitFilm Express**. And there is a specific tutorial: https://hitfilm.com/express/heads-up
- **BlackMagic Fusion** https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion/ which has a free version
- And, as always **Blender**. https://www.blender.org/ with a ton of tutorials regarding motion tracking. https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+motion+tracking

---

Of course, you can do that in After Effects too.

---

Regarding the first part, the animation, well there are a ton of options too.

You can make a frame by frame animation, animate that in CSS of a web page and a screen capture, use the compositing program, use a 3D program, use stop motion using paper cuts...

---

Note one thing.

That is NOT augmented reality. That is just a special effect.

Augmented reality is a real time 3D object or event using the device's camera and displaying it on the device screen.